# Is there a way to get Content Security Policy 2 to work with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager, content-security-policy

I added the Content-Security-Policy header to our servers' responses, but the browser throws errors when Google Tag Manager (GTM) injects Custom HTML tags.

CSP3 has 'strict-dynamic' which appears custom-made for GTM, but currently only Chrome supports it, and CSP3 is a Working Draft.

I wrote code to get the Custom HTML tags via the GTM API, hoping I might take the scripts' hashes and add them to the header, but I found that the JavaScript provided by the API didn't match what GTM was injecting into the DOM, because GTM minifies/obfuscates the scripts before injecting them.

Now I'm wondering if maybe, just maybe, there's a way to tell GTM to add a nonce to each script it injects, but I can't find any documentation to support this hope/fantasy.

Has anyone run into this, and found a way to fix this?

(I can't just extract the hosts from the scripts as mentioned here - [How to make Google Tag Manager and Content-Security-Policy coexist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974419/how-to-make-google-tag-manager-and-content-security-policy-coexist) - because the Custom HTML tags added by our Marketing Team are  tags with non-empty bodies, not just  tags with a source attribute and no body.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Google Tag Manager and Content-Security-Policy coexist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974419/how-to-make-google-tag-manager-and-content-security-policy-coexist)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100704/gtm-not-propagating-nonce-to-custom-html-tags