# GTM not propagating nonce to Custom HTML tags

Tags: google-tag-manager, content-security-policy

In order to implement Content-Security-Policy, I need to pass `nonce` to GTM to allow tags.
Using **nonce-aware** version of GTM snippet works great for all tag types except **Custom HTML**.

Is there a way to pass `nonce` to **Custom HTML** and allow custom scripts, without using `unsafe-inline`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to add the `nonce` attribute to the Custom HTML scripts, it must be first defined as a GTM variable:

1. Add `id="gtmScript"` to the nonce-aware version of GTM snippet - this will be used to target the element and capture `nonce`.

```html
<script id="gtmScript" nonce="{GENERATED_NONCE}">
  // GTM function
</script>
```

2. In GTM, create a new variable that will capture the nonce.
   Use **DOM Element** type, and select the ID of the GTM snippet.

[image: GTM Variable configuration for nonce]

---

Now that the `nonce` variable is available in the GTM, add it to the Custom HTML script.

```html
<script nonce="{{nonce}}">
  console.log("CSP-allowed script with nonce:", "{{nonce}}");
</script>
```

If the tag is not firing, check the **Support document.write**. This can be a key step in Single Page Applications.
The GTM Custom HTML script is now nonce-allowed and fires as expected.
Of course, any assets used by this script will now need to be allowed in the CSP header.

[image: GTM Custom HTML configuration]

---

#### Script within a script

Many tracking scripts are creating and firing additional script within themselves.
These will also be blocked as inline-scripts.
Find out where and how they are created, and add `nonce` to them as well.

Usually, the code looks similar to this:

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.async = true;
script.src = "https://tracking.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
```

Edit this part of the code and insert the `nonce` variable, in the same manner along with other attributes.

```js
script.nonce = "{{nonce}}";
```

Again, pay attention and whitelist any necessary assets that are now being blocked from this newly allowed script.

That's it - Custom HTML script is now fully CSP-allowed.

---

Source and disclaimer: I'm the author of [expanded dev.to guide](https://dev.to/matijamrkaic/using-google-tag-manager-with-a-content-security-policy-9ai)

Comment: Hello, i'm not sure how to implement "Script within a script" part. You suggest to download third-party script a modifying it? Than instead of <script src="third-party-link"></script> use inside GTM Custom HTML <script>modified code</script>?

Comment: @ETNyx If the tracker you use is creating and loading a new script then you just need to augment it with the same `nonce`, not replace it (the sample code above is really a good representation of these kinds of trackers). If you have `<script src="third-party-link">` kind of tracker, then obviously only `<script src="third-party-link" nonce="{{nonce}}">` will be needed.
The rule of thumb is to follow the console errors caused by your CSP and fix them as they come up.

Comment: Thanks for your response, after hours of headache i crack mine problem. This "third-party-link" use document.write so this tiny little checkbox in GTM did some magic and solve mine problem, nonce is enough as you told. Once again thanks.

Comment: @MatijaMrkaic I'm having trouble with this actually working. I created the demo script as a tag and used the nonce-aware GTM snippet, but no mater what, the demo script doesn't run. For fun I added "unsafe-inline' and the demo script runs fine, including outputting the correct nonce value in console.(So the variable collection is working fine)

Comment: @Aaryn Have you checked that "Support document.write" checkbox? Also, if "unsafe-inline" is not allowed, is there any error in console?

Comment: @MatijaMrkaic I followed the exact steps written here. It only works on Safari but not on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge (I don't even see the `console.log("CSP-allowed script with nonce:", "{{nonce}}");` on these browsers).

I'm using Mac 10.15.1 and all the browsers are the latest version. If this works on all browsers for you, could you please help me to understand what the issue is?
[Here is the link to my question][1] including the screenshots. 
CC: @ETNyx

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598175/gtm-nonce-aware-script-does-not-propagate-the-nonce-to-all-scripts-that-it-adds

Comment: @Keyhan If the issue is up to the Chrome masking the nonce attribute so tag manager is unable to grab it and store it as a variable, you could try to bypass that by adding a `data-nonce` attribute and using that instead to access nonce in GTM.

Comment: @MatijaMrkaic thank you. It worked with the approach you mentioned. There is just one issue that I don't know how to fix and it's happening in Firefox. It complains about the use of `eval` in the gtm script. When I put `unsafe-eval` in script-src the errors go away. But I know this is not recommended to include `unsafe-eval`. By any chance, do you know how I can tackle this one? Here is where the error is happending

`// Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
(function(w,g){w[g]=w[g]||{};w[g].e=function(s){return eval(s);};})(window,'google_tag_manager');(function(){ ...`

Comment: @Keyhan Great! Unfortunately, the only thing you can do about script using `eval` is to remove it. It simply is not safe, and allowing `unsafe-eval` is defeating the whole purpose of CSP. Good luck talking with marketing :)

Comment: @MatijaMrkaic hahaaa :D You know it's gonna be a tough one... . But I wonder how the rest of the browsers (Safari, Chrome and Edge) don't complain about `eval` and it's only Firefox that complains. How come those browsers without adding `unsafe-eval` load the scripts 

Comment: Any idea why `document.write` is required to insert a script with a nonce, even when the script is simply logging something to the console?

Comment: @MatijaMrkaic Any solutions for react-gtm-module package?

Comment: On my side I had to use `script.setAttribute("nonce", "{{nonce}}");` instead of `script.nonce = "{{nonce}}";` for it to work on Chrome

Comment: Won't this approach require 'unsafe-eval' to be provided in CSP policy? (according to https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/csp#custom_javascript_variables)

Comment: The "nonce" attribute was not working, so I used "data-nonce" instead.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler and more secure way to fix the issue with GTM not propagating nonce to Custom HTML tags.

1. Ensure that you have included the nonce attribute in the GTM script tag, as described in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/csp):

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script nonce='{SERVER-GENERATED-NONCE}'>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;var n=d.querySelector('[nonce]');
n&&j.setAttribute('nonce',n.nonce||n.getAttribute('nonce'));f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

2. Next, append `'strict-dynamic'` to the `script-src` section of the Content Security Policy (CSP) header, as demonstrated below. `'strict-dynamic'` simplifies the process of implementing a CSP based on nonces or hashes, as it automatically permits the execution of scripts generated by a previously trusted script. This action also facilitates the use of various third-party JavaScript libraries and widgets, including GTM.

```http
Content-Security-Policy:
  script-src 'nonce-{SERVER-GENERATED-NONCE}' 'strict-dynamic';
  img-src www.googletagmanager.com;
  object-src 'none';
  base-uri 'none';
```

Additionally, it's a wise practice to block `object-src` to prevent the use of potentially hazardous plugins like Flash and `base-uri` to safeguard against attackers altering the locations of scripts loaded from relative URLs.

With this solution, there is no need to add an insecure `data-nonce` attribute. and also there is no need to change anything in the GTM custom scripts.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the same problem as others with the original solution proposed by Matija Mrkaic. His article was very useful but I was finding the `nonce` data attribute to be returning a blank value.

To fix this I added a `data-nonce` attribute to the GTM script with a variable in Tag Manager to extract the nonce value (similar to Matija Mrkaic. This new variable was called `data-nonce`). I then added a custom HTML tag in GTM that removes the `data-nonce` attribute once it is loaded.

GTM code:

```
<script id="gtmScript" nonce='{{csp_nonce}}' data-nonce='{{csp_nonce}}'>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;var n=d.querySelector('[nonce]');
n&&j.setAttribute('nonce',n.nonce||n.getAttribute('nonce'));f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','{{GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID}}');</script>
```

GTM Custom HTML tag to remove the nonce value once it was loaded:

```
<script nonce="{{data-nonce}}">
    console.log("Inline script to remove data-nonce.");
    document.getElementById("gtmScript").removeAttribute("data-nonce");
</script>
```

This solution is far from perfect but I have so far been unable to find a method to pass 'secrets' to GTM. Exposing the nonce value in the DOM is not recommended, the theory behind this 'temporary' solution is to only expose it for a short period of time until loaded into the Google Tag Manager variable.

Comments/suggestions welcome, many thanks.

Comment: It can look like the nonce is blank because it is hidden in a browser preview, but it is accessible via JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67123053/3370010

Answer (score -1):

For anyone having the issue with Chrome hiding the nonce attribute (noted by Keyhan and Dan in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65100705/3370010), I found that Google Tag Manager has a setting to get a variable from a global "JavaScript Variable".

[image: Google Tag Manager Configuration for JavaScript Variable]

You just need to set that global variable first. If you add Google Tag Manager dynamically, it can be set before your Google Tag Manager script.

```js
window.nonceForCustomScripts = nonce;
```

If you are just inserting the code into the Google Tag Manger script, it would look something like

```js
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;var n=d.querySelector('[nonce]');
            n&&j.setAttribute('nonce',n.nonce||n.getAttribute('nonce'));
// Added code
w.nonceForCustomScripts = n.nonce||n.getAttribute('nonce');
// End added code
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','your-gtm-id');
```

This is more secure than adding a data-nonce attribute because it prevents CSS-based attacks such as the one listed in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/nonce