# Strict-dynamic nonce directive breaks scripts called by other scripts in CSPv2 browsers (e.g., Safari)

Tags: safari, content-security-policy, nonce

In browsers like Safari that (still) only support `CSPv2`, when I have 'strict-dynamic' and 'nonce-AAA' directives in my Content Security Policy along with all the appropriate domains, the browser will call a script loader but not execute a 2nd script called by the script loader.

For instance, if I have a `CSP` like:

`script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-AAA' https:;`

on a site that includes googletagmanager, convertexperiments, or another script loader, the first script will execute but the second script will not, and the browser will throw a standard script-src `CSP` error.

I expected that Safari, etc would ignore the 'strict-dynamic' and 'nonce-' directives, but it seems to only ignore the 'strict-dynamic' directive, where the 'nonce-' directive causes script loaders to break.

Recommendations about how to craft the `CSP` so that it can be UA-agnostic/work with both modern browsers and `CSPv2` browsers without losing 'strict-dynamic'?

Tangentially, why would a `CSPv2` browser be somewhat nonce aware without being able to use it in conjunction with 'strict-dynamic'?

Please note that the question isn't about whether 'unsafe-inline' is a good idea; the example is about how permissive I'm trying to make my policy to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

> For instance, if I have a CSP like:
>  `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-AAA' https:;`
>  on a site that includes googletagmanager,
> convertexperiments, or another script loader, the first script will
> execute but the second script will not, and the browser will throw a
> standard script-src CSP error.

[GoogleTagManager propagating `'nonce-value'` into child scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100704/gtm-not-propagating-nonce-to-custom-html-tags) except Custom HTML tags. To allow inline scripts in Custom HTML tags you can use '`hash-source'`.

The *convertexperiments* WP plugin can be easily modified to support `'nonce-value'` (minor edits in class-convert-script.php file) or just move inline script to external file.

> I expected that Safari, etc would ignore the 'strict-dynamic' and
> 'nonce-' directives, but it seems to only ignore the 'strict-dynamic'
> directive, where the 'nonce-' directive causes script loaders to
> break.

Safari [does not support](https://csplite.com/csp/test217/#safari) 'strict-dynamic', but is [does support](https://csplite.com/csp/test214/#safari) `'nonce-value'`. And `'nonce-value'` cancells `'unsafe-inline'` therefore all inline scripts became blocked.
You have to craft CSP in *browsers backward compatibility mode* as Google does it (you can check the CSP header in https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor for example). Since your instance of CSP already is in this mode, you need just to modify your code for `'nonce-value'` support (+ `'hash-value'` where it suitable).

Yes, Safari left no easy ways to implement CSP.