# Using GTM w/ Next.js can't get past CSP

Tags: next.js, google-tag-manager, content-security-policy

I have custom CSP headers in `next.config.js` that are loaded into the head of the page in `./layouts`.

```
const defaultCSP = {
    "script-src": [
        "'self'",
        "'unsafe-eval'",
        "'unsafe-inline'",
        `'nonce-${nonce}'`,
        "tagmanager.google.com/",
        "googletagmanager.com",       
    ],
    "script-src-elem": [
        "'self'",
        `'nonce-${nonce}'`,
        "tagmanager.google.com/",
        "googletagmanager.com",
    ],
};
```

Trying to use `react-gtm-module-nonce` like so in `_app.tsx`

```
useEffect(() => {
    TagManager.initialize({
        gtmId: GTM_CONTAINER_ID,
        auth: GTM_AUTH,
        preview: GTM_PREVIEW,
        nonce: NONCE,
    });
}, []);
```

but when the app is loaded I see the following error

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self' 'nonce-SOME_NONCE_VALUE' tagmanager.google.com/ googletagmanager.com Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-r7NoIbKRzEIuATQ9EL7eN52m5xWoVwuBBTdGzzqnMbY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

It seems like I have the necessary items to run GTM but can't get past CSP. Any clues as to what's happening here? I've tried adding 'unsafe-inline' to `script-src-elem` but then it shows that it will be ignored if there's a nonce.

Comment: Have you fixed this?

Comment: Following thread resolved this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100704/gtm-not-propagating-nonce-to-custom-html-tags