# Add nonce to script tag

Tags: javascript, nonce

I want to add a nonce to a dynamically constructed script tag. The below does NOT add any nonce to the generated script tag. Anyone an idea how the nonce can be added?

```js
var _wss = document.createElement('script');
_wss.nonce = 'random-string';
_wss.type = 'text/javascript';
_wss.charset = 'utf-8';
_wss.async = true;
_wss.src = "url";
var __wss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
__wss.parentNode.insertBefore(_wss, __wss);
```

The result is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="url"></script>
```

Expected result:

```
<script nonce="random-string" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="url"></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please share more details - what happens instead when you run that code? What would be the expected result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran your code on this stackoverflow page, and it worked.

I think the problem you're having is that you're expecting to see the nonce as an attribute of the script tag, but it's only available in javascript as a property.

The tag looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="url"></script>
```

But if you run

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].nonce)
```

it will show `"random-string"`

The reason is security. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce#accessing_nonces_and_nonce_hiding. Specifically

> For security reasons, the nonce content attribute is hidden (an empty
> string will be returned).
>
> The nonce property is the only way to access nonces:

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `strict-dynamic` CSP source instead of `nonce` if you want to dynamically import/construct scripts.

> The **strict-dynamic** source expression specifies that the trust explicitly given to a script present in the markup, by accompanying it with a nonce or a hash, shall be propagated to **all the scripts loaded by that root script**. At the same time, any allow-list or source expressions such as 'self' or 'unsafe-inline' are ignored.
>
> Source [MDN - CSP: script-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src)

You can also read more about it and see some examples at [Content Security Policy (CSP)
Quick Reference Guide](https://content-security-policy.com/strict-dynamic/).